# Nidda learning Torah

Tags: halacha, niddah

Aside from the fact that Poskim debate whether women should/shouldn't learn Torah. Can a niddah Learn torah Via (Shuir, Reading, Looking In)?

Comment: Why wouldn't she be allowed? By the way, all single girls above puberty are niddah so you just knocked out Jewish high schools and seminaries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Tosefta (Berachot 2:12) explictily states that they can:

> הזבין והזבות והנדות והיולדות מותרין לקרות בתורה בנביאים ובכתובים ולשנות במשנה במדרש בהלכות ובאגדות

In the version of the Tosefta recorded in the Babylonian Talmud ([Berachot 23a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=22&format=pdf)) the female categories are missing:

> הזבים והמצורעים ובאין על נדות מותרים לקרות בתורה ובנביאים ובכתובים לשנות במשנה וגמרא ובהלכות ובאגדות

But in the version in the Palestinian Talmud (Berachot 3:4) the female categories are mentioned:

> תני זבין וזבות נדות ויולדות קורין בתורה ושונין מדרש והלכות והגדות

There is some discussion among *rishonim*, though, of customs where women would not enter a synagogue, say God's name, or touch a Torah scroll while a *niddah*. R. Moses Isserles cites this discussion in [O.C. 88](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x454) and [Y.D. 195](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5377). His conclusion is that the main approach is that it is allowed, but in his place these customs were upheld.

In any event, merely "learning Torah" does not seem to be mentioned as part of these customs.

Comment: Thank you boss man

Comment: @alex the most important thing for a nidda to learn more than any 'torah' is what is a hargosho. Meaning what she feels when being a niddah. many internet sites will tell you but no sefer. so more important to study internet that torah. rabbis who dont have internet are not allowed to pasken woman shaalos. I seriously mean all this.